Solidity error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
I am following this tutorial but I am stuck in Lesson 5. I am using WSL:Ubuntu on my Windows machine along with Ganache. When I run node deploy.js, a smart contract was deployed and gas was spent, but the output has the error message Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode. The full output:
deploying... please wait...
Error: processing response error (body="{\"id\":51,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\",\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:12745)\\n    at Miner.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:36703)\\n    at async Miner.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:35116)\\n    at async Miner.mine (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:39680)\\n    at async Blockchain.mine (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:60063)\\n    at async Promise.all (index 0)\\n    at async TransactionPool.emit (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\node_modules\\\\emittery\\\\index.js:303:3)\",\"code\":-32000,\"name\":\"RuntimeError\",\"data\":{\"hash\":\"0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c\",\"programCounter\":23,\"result\":\"0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c\",\"reason\":null,\"message\":\"invalid opcode\"}}}", error={"code":-32000,"data":{"hash":"0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c","programCounter":23,"result":"0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\":[\"0x02f9095182053908852e90edd000852e90edd000836691b78080b908f46080604052348015600e575f80fd5b506108d88061001c5f395ff3fe608060405234801561000f575f80fd5b5060043610610055575f3560e01c80632e64cec1146100595780636057361d146100775780636f760f41146100935780638bab8dd5146100af5780639e7a13ad146100df575b5f80fd5b610061610110565b60405161006e919061029f565b60405180910390f35b610091600480360381019061008c91906102f3565b610118565b005b6100ad60048036038101906100a8919061045a565b610121565b005b6100c960048036038101906100c491906104b4565b6101a5565b6040516100d6919061029f565b60405180910390f35b6100f960048036038101906100f491906102f3565b6101d2565b60405161010792919061055b565b60405180910390f35b5f8054905090565b805f8190555050565b6001604051806040016040528083815260200184815250908060018154018082558091505060019003905f5260205f2090600202015f909190919091505f820151815f0155602082015181600101908161017b9190610783565b5050508060028360405161018f919061088c565b9081526020016040518091039020819055505050565b6002818051602081018201805184825260208301602085012081835280955050505050505f915090505481565b600181815481106101e1575f80fd5b905f5260205f2090600202015f91509050805f015490806001018054610206906105b6565b80601f0160208091040260200160405190810160405280929190818152602001828054610232906105b6565b801561027d5780601f106102545761010080835404028352916020019161027d565b820191905f5260205f20905b81548152906001019060200180831161026057829003601f168201915b5050505050905082565b5f819050919050565b61029981610287565b82525050565b5f6020820190506102b25f830184610290565b92915050565b5f604051905090565b5f80fd5b5f80fd5b6102d281610287565b81146102dc575f80fd5b50565b5f813590506102ed816102c9565b92915050565b5f60208284031215610308576103076102c1565b5b5f610315848285016102df565b91505092915050565b5f80fd5b5f80fd5b5f601f19601f8301169050919050565b7f4e487b71000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f52604160045260245ffd5b61036c82610326565b810181811067ffffffffffffffff8211171561038b5761038a610336565b5b80604052505050565b5f61039d6102b8565b90506103a98282610363565b919050565b5f67ffffffffffffffff8211156103c8576103c7610336565b5b6103d182610326565b9050602081019050919050565b828183375f83830152505050565b5f6103fe6103f9846103ae565b610394565b90508281526020810184848401111561041a57610419610322565b5b6104258482856103de565b509392505050565b5f82601f8301126104415761044061031e565b5b81356104518482602086016103ec565b91505092915050565b5f80604083850312156104705761046f6102c1565b5b5f83013567ffffffffffffffff81111561048d5761048c6102c5565b5b6104998582860161042d565b92505060206104aa858286016102df565b9150509250929050565b5f602082840312156104c9576104c86102c1565b5b5f82013567ffffffffffffffff8111156104e6576104e56102c5565b5b6104f28482850161042d565b91505092915050565b5f81519050919050565b5f82825260208201905092915050565b8281835e5f83830152505050565b5f61052d826104fb565b6105378185610505565b9350610547818560208601610515565b61055081610326565b840191505092915050565b5f60408201905061056e5f830185610290565b81810360208301526105808184610523565b90509392505050565b7f4e487b71000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f52602260045260245ffd5b5f60028204905060018216806105cd57607f821691505b6020821081036105e0576105df610589565b5b50919050565b5f819050815f5260205f209050919050565b5f6020601f8301049050919050565b5f82821b905092915050565b5f600883026106427fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff82610607565b61064c8683610607565b95508019841693508086168417925050509392505050565b5f819050919050565b5f61068761068261067d84610287565b610664565b610287565b9050919050565b5f819050919050565b6106a08361066d565b6106b46106ac8261068e565b848454610613565b825550505050565b5f90565b6106c86106bc565b6106d3818484610697565b505050565b5b818110156106f6576106eb5f826106c0565b6001810190506106d9565b5050565b601f82111561073b5761070c816105e6565b610715846105f8565b81016020851015610724578190505b610738610730856105f8565b8301826106d8565b50505b505050565b5f82821c905092915050565b5f61075b5f1984600802610740565b1980831691505092915050565b5f610773838361074c565b9150826002028217905092915050565b61078c826104fb565b67ffffffffffffffff8111156107a5576107a4610336565b5b6107af82546105b6565b6107ba8282856106fa565b5f60209050601f8311600181146107eb575f84156107d9578287015190505b6107e38582610768565b86555061084a565b601f1984166107f9866105e6565b5f5b82811015610820578489015182556001820191506020850194506020810190506107fb565b8683101561083d5784890151610839601f89168261074c565b8355505b6001600288020188555050505b505050505050565b5f81905092915050565b5f610866826104fb565b6108708185610852565b9350610880818560208601610515565b80840191505092915050565b5f610897828461085c565b91508190509291505056fea264697066735822122049603a09a0109c6d339e363e5431144aa882355f048416e645d9db9f7c21e7d064736f6c634300081a0033c001a049725071d51578fff0324fdc4c8d931bc8bd814511bf47c7d96e2fc0e250b03da05ed7a4e8572c7b80c7ea4700ec07617ece0a7063aa36069b295ea7001eedcb88\"],\"id\":51,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://172.21.192.1:7545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at /home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:313:32
    at step (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'processing response error',
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  body: '{"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:12745)\\n    at Miner.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:36703)\\n    at async Miner.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:35116)\\n    at async Miner.mine (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:39680)\\n    at async Blockchain.mine (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:60063)\\n    at async Promise.all (index 0)\\n    at async TransactionPool.emit (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\node_modules\\\\emittery\\\\index.js:303:3)","code":-32000,"name":"RuntimeError","data":{"hash":"0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c","programCounter":23,"result":"0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}}',
  error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
      at getResult (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
      at processJsonFunc (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:356:22)
      at /home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:288:46
      at step (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (/home/guyser/Working_Dir/My_Dev/learning_and_sandboxing/tut_for_blockchain_dev/by_freecodecamp/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: -32000,
    data: {
      hash: '0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c',
      programCounter: 23,
      result: '0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c',
      reason: null,
      message: 'invalid opcode'
    }
  },
  requestBody: '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["0x02f9095182053908852e90edd000852e90edd000836691b78080b908f46080604052348015600e575f80fd5b506108d88061001c5f395ff3fe608060405234801561000f575f80fd5b5060043610610055575f3560e01c80632e64cec1146100595780636057361d146100775780636f760f41146100935780638bab8dd5146100af5780639e7a13ad146100df575b5f80fd5b610061610110565b60405161006e919061029f565b60405180910390f35b610091600480360381019061008c91906102f3565b610118565b005b6100ad60048036038101906100a8919061045a565b610121565b005b6100c960048036038101906100c491906104b4565b6101a5565b6040516100d6919061029f565b60405180910390f35b6100f960048036038101906100f491906102f3565b6101d2565b60405161010792919061055b565b60405180910390f35b5f8054905090565b805f8190555050565b6001604051806040016040528083815260200184815250908060018154018082558091505060019003905f5260205f2090600202015f909190919091505f820151815f0155602082015181600101908161017b9190610783565b5050508060028360405161018f919061088c565b9081526020016040518091039020819055505050565b6002818051602081018201805184825260208301602085012081835280955050505050505f915090505481565b600181815481106101e1575f80fd5b905f5260205f2090600202015f91509050805f015490806001018054610206906105b6565b80601f0160208091040260200160405190810160405280929190818152602001828054610232906105b6565b801561027d5780601f106102545761010080835404028352916020019161027d565b820191905f5260205f20905b81548152906001019060200180831161026057829003601f168201915b5050505050905082565b5f819050919050565b61029981610287565b82525050565b5f6020820190506102b25f830184610290565b92915050565b5f604051905090565b5f80fd5b5f80fd5b6102d281610287565b81146102dc575f80fd5b50565b5f813590506102ed816102c9565b92915050565b5f60208284031215610308576103076102c1565b5b5f610315848285016102df565b91505092915050565b5f80fd5b5f80fd5b5f601f19601f8301169050919050565b7f4e487b71000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f52604160045260245ffd5b61036c82610326565b810181811067ffffffffffffffff8211171561038b5761038a610336565b5b80604052505050565b5f61039d6102b8565b90506103a98282610363565b919050565b5f67ffffffffffffffff8211156103c8576103c7610336565b5b6103d182610326565b9050602081019050919050565b828183375f83830152505050565b5f6103fe6103f9846103ae565b610394565b90508281526020810184848401111561041a57610419610322565b5b6104258482856103de565b509392505050565b5f82601f8301126104415761044061031e565b5b81356104518482602086016103ec565b91505092915050565b5f80604083850312156104705761046f6102c1565b5b5f83013567ffffffffffffffff81111561048d5761048c6102c5565b5b6104998582860161042d565b92505060206104aa858286016102df565b9150509250929050565b5f602082840312156104c9576104c86102c1565b5b5f82013567ffffffffffffffff8111156104e6576104e56102c5565b5b6104f28482850161042d565b91505092915050565b5f81519050919050565b5f82825260208201905092915050565b8281835e5f83830152505050565b5f61052d826104fb565b6105378185610505565b9350610547818560208601610515565b61055081610326565b840191505092915050565b5f60408201905061056e5f830185610290565b81810360208301526105808184610523565b90509392505050565b7f4e487b71000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f52602260045260245ffd5b5f60028204905060018216806105cd57607f821691505b6020821081036105e0576105df610589565b5b50919050565b5f819050815f5260205f209050919050565b5f6020601f8301049050919050565b5f82821b905092915050565b5f600883026106427fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff82610607565b61064c8683610607565b95508019841693508086168417925050509392505050565b5f819050919050565b5f61068761068261067d84610287565b610664565b610287565b9050919050565b5f819050919050565b6106a08361066d565b6106b46106ac8261068e565b848454610613565b825550505050565b5f90565b6106c86106bc565b6106d3818484610697565b505050565b5b818110156106f6576106eb5f826106c0565b6001810190506106d9565b5050565b601f82111561073b5761070c816105e6565b610715846105f8565b81016020851015610724578190505b610738610730856105f8565b8301826106d8565b50505b505050565b5f82821c905092915050565b5f61075b5f1984600802610740565b1980831691505092915050565b5f610773838361074c565b9150826002028217905092915050565b61078c826104fb565b67ffffffffffffffff8111156107a5576107a4610336565b5b6107af82546105b6565b6107ba8282856106fa565b5f60209050601f8311600181146107eb575f84156107d9578287015190505b6107e38582610768565b86555061084a565b601f1984166107f9866105e6565b5f5b82811015610820578489015182556001820191506020850194506020810190506107fb565b8683101561083d5784890151610839601f89168261074c565b8355505b6001600288020188555050505b505050505050565b5f81905092915050565b5f610866826104fb565b6108708185610852565b9350610880818560208601610515565b80840191505092915050565b5f610897828461085c565b91508190509291505056fea264697066735822122049603a09a0109c6d339e363e5431144aa882355f048416e645d9db9f7c21e7d064736f6c634300081a0033c001a049725071d51578fff0324fdc4c8d931bc8bd814511bf47c7d96e2fc0e250b03da05ed7a4e8572c7b80c7ea4700ec07617ece0a7063aa36069b295ea7001eedcb88"],"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
  requestMethod: 'POST',
  url: 'http://172.21.192.1:7545',
  transaction: {
    type: 2,
    chainId: 1337,
    nonce: 8,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x2e90edd000', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x2e90edd000', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasPrice: null,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x6691b7', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: null,
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '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',
    accessList: [],
    hash: '0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c',
    v: 1,
    r: '0x49725071d51578fff0324fdc4c8d931bc8bd814511bf47c7d96e2fc0e250b03d',
    s: '0x5ed7a4e8572c7b80c7ea4700ec07617ece0a7063aa36069b295ea7001eedcb88',
    from: '0xC3eeC33956e6aaF92876ff44D9D4b13Fc2D9212d',
    confirmations: 0
  },
  transactionHash: '0xe64077d05e621346e0c8f7139feda785ff7605e3f07b71428ec97d87da883d2c'
}

npm list shows:
├── @types/bn.js@4.11.6 extraneous
├── @types/node@20.14.9 extraneous
├── @types/pbkdf2@3.1.2 extraneous
├── @types/secp256k1@4.0.6 extraneous
├── ansi-regex@4.1.1 extraneous
├── ansi-styles@3.2.1 extraneous
├── base-x@3.0.9 extraneous
├── blakejs@1.2.1 extraneous
├── bn.js@4.12.0 extraneous
├── browserify-aes@1.2.0 extraneous
├── bs58@4.0.1 extraneous
├── bs58check@2.1.2 extraneous
├── buffer-from@1.1.2 extraneous
├── buffer-xor@1.0.3 extraneous
├── camelcase@5.3.1 extraneous
├── cipher-base@1.0.4 extraneous
├── cliui@5.0.0 extraneous
├── color-convert@1.9.3 extraneous
├── color-name@1.1.3 extraneous
├── create-hash@1.2.0 extraneous
├── create-hmac@1.1.7 extraneous
├── cross-spawn@6.0.5 extraneous
├── decamelize@1.2.0 extraneous
├── elliptic@6.5.5 extraneous
├── emoji-regex@7.0.3 extraneous
├── end-of-stream@1.4.4 extraneous
├── ethereum-cryptography@0.1.3 extraneous
├── ethereumjs-util@6.2.1 extraneous
├── ethers@5.7.2
├── ethjs-util@0.1.6 extraneous
├── evp_bytestokey@1.0.3 extraneous
├── execa@1.0.0 extraneous
├── find-up@3.0.0 extraneous
├── fs-extra@11.2.0
├── ganache-cli@6.12.2
├── get-caller-file@2.0.5 extraneous
├── get-stream@4.1.0 extraneous
├── hash-base@3.1.0 extraneous
├── invert-kv@2.0.0 extraneous
├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 extraneous
├── is-hex-prefixed@1.0.0 extraneous
├── is-stream@1.1.0 extraneous
├── isexe@2.0.0 extraneous
├── keccak@3.0.4 extraneous
├── lcid@2.0.0 extraneous
├── locate-path@3.0.0 extraneous
├── map-age-cleaner@0.1.3 extraneous
├── md5.js@1.3.5 extraneous
├── mem@4.3.0 extraneous
├── mimic-fn@2.1.0 extraneous
├── nice-try@1.0.5 extraneous
├── node-addon-api@2.0.2 extraneous
├── node-gyp-build@4.8.1 extraneous
├── npm-run-path@2.0.2 extraneous
├── once@1.4.0 extraneous
├── os-locale@3.1.0 extraneous
├── p-defer@1.0.0 extraneous
├── p-finally@1.0.0 extraneous
├── p-is-promise@2.1.0 extraneous
├── p-limit@2.3.0 extraneous
├── p-locate@3.0.0 extraneous
├── p-try@2.2.0 extraneous
├── path-exists@3.0.0 extraneous
├── path-key@2.0.1 extraneous
├── pbkdf2@3.1.2 extraneous
├── pump@3.0.0 extraneous
├── randombytes@2.1.0 extraneous
├── readable-stream@3.6.2 extraneous
├── require-directory@2.1.1 extraneous
├── require-main-filename@2.0.0 extraneous
├── ripemd160@2.0.2 extraneous
├── rlp@2.2.7 extraneous
├── safe-buffer@5.2.1 extraneous
├── secp256k1@4.0.3 extraneous
├── set-blocking@2.0.0 extraneous
├── setimmediate@1.0.5 extraneous
├── sha.js@2.4.11 extraneous
├── shebang-command@1.2.0 extraneous
├── shebang-regex@1.0.0 extraneous
├── signal-exit@3.0.7 extraneous
├── solc@0.8.26
├── source-map-support@0.5.12 extraneous
├── source-map@0.6.1 extraneous
├── string_decoder@1.3.0 extraneous
├── string-width@3.1.0 extraneous
├── strip-ansi@5.2.0 extraneous
├── strip-eof@1.0.0 extraneous
├── strip-hex-prefix@1.0.0 extraneous
├── undici-types@5.26.5 extraneous
├── util-deprecate@1.0.2 extraneous
├── which-module@2.0.1 extraneous
├── which@1.3.1 extraneous
├── wrap-ansi@5.1.0 extraneous
├── wrappy@1.0.2 extraneous
├── y18n@4.0.3 extraneous
├── yargs-parser@13.1.2 extraneous
└── yargs@13.2.4 extraneous

The deploy.js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  // Your code here
  // http://172.21.192.1:1212
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://172.21.192.1:1212"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "fghfgh8f172678677777777fhfghggggggggggggggggggggffffffffffffffffffffff",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const overrides = {
    gasPrice: 200000000000, // Can set this >= to the number read from Ganache window
    gasLimit: 6721975, // Use the same gasLimit as read from Ganache window (or a bit higher if still having issue)
  };
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("deploying... please wait...");

  // actually deploying the contract with ethers
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(overrides); // await makes it wait here for contract to deploy completely
  //console.log(contract);
  console.log(">>>>>> This is deployment transaction: ");
  console.log(contract.deployTransaction);

  // wait for 1 block to pass before getting the receipt
  const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.await(1);
  console.log(">>>>>> This is deployment receipt: ");
  console.log(deploymentReceipt);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

The package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ethers": "5.7.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "solc": "0.8.26"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol"
  }
}

The SimpleStorage.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.26;

// pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    // uint256[] public anArray;
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}

I have tried all the things that I have found on the internet, including ensuring the compiler matches with the one specified on the script. For example, solc@0.8.26 and pragma solidity 0.8.26 in the .sol file. I have also been making sure Ganache allows the connection from WSL, and restarting Ganache. Nothing seems to be able to get rid of the error and show me the expected outputs.

The problem is from ganache, this question is answered here as well:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83222/vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-invalid-opcode-error
